# httpClient 4 & Java understanding

Tags: jmeter

What use of `httpClient 4` & `Java`. Need an easy understanding word. I am confused if I am not used this all then also script is created, As per jmeter property set default httpClient 4 but in property active

`jmeter.httpsampler=HTTPSampler`

and

`# HttpClient4.x` is commented `#jmeter.httpsampler=HttpClient4`

Why?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand what you want. But JMeter uses HttpClient4 as default implementation.

You can change that by setting property :

> jmeter.httpsampler

But I don't advise it.

If you look at jmeter.properties, the following lines which would set Java implementation are commented :

> ## jmeter.httpsampler=HTTPSampler
>
> ## jmeter.httpsampler=Java

You can also change the implementation with:

- [Http Request Default](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults)
- [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)

Comment: what use of java & you are right httpsclient 4 is a default but why mention in property file as #jmeter.httpsampler=HttpClient4 (its a commented then how it work) and jmeter.httpsampler=HTTPSampler  HTTPSampler is a same httpClient 4